# call python script in java application (Error in python import)

Tags: python, java, docx, python-docx

I call my python script with java and also pass variables. My The script alone in a PyCharm project works so far, only if I call it via Java (InteliJ) nothing happens.

The program should pass values ​​to my script via Java so that the script changes and saves values ​​in a Word Document (docx).

If I use the version of my script in the Intelij folder, it has problems importing docx.

I think the problem is that in the PyCharm project the docx data is directly in the project. This is not the case with Intelij and it should access the system data from docx.

I have already completely reinstalled lxml and docx but to no avail.

How do I have to change my program structure or my script so that it works.

Java:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class runPython {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python", "C://Users//Notebook//IdeaProjects//bhTool_bridge//scripts//main.py", "Annemarie Brekow");
            Process process = builder.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Python:

```
from docx import Document
import sys
import os

document = Document('C:/Users/Notebook/IdeaProjects/bhTool_bridge/template/Muster_Rechnung.docx')

workingdirectory=os.getcwd()

def find_replace(paragraph_keyword, draft_keyword, paragraph):
    if paragraph_keyword in paragraph.text:
        # print("found")
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(paragraph_keyword, draft_keyword)


for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    find_replace("$Kunden-Name", "Annemarie Brekow", paragraph)
    print(paragraph.text)

document.save("C:/Users/Notebook/IdeaProjects/bhTool_bridge/template/Muster_Rechnung.docx")
```

EDIT:
Errormsg

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Notebook\IdeaProjects\bhTool_bridge\scripts\main.py", line 2, in 
> from docx import Document
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
>
> > > 

Comment: Does the script work when you call it from cmd? Most likely PyCharm starts its scripts and installs its libraries in a virtual environment that you do not use when running script with a cmd command.

Comment: @matszwecja if i call it via "python path" it runs completly normal how it should

Comment: java could start process with different environment set (i.e. sys.path), and in unforeseen working directory. Could it be the issue?

Comment: @MaciejWrobel how excatly u mean that ? and how should i force him to process it in the right environment ? I understand it in such a way that he simply executes it as if I were calling it via cmd, just with the values. but obviously he doesn't

Comment: when process is spawned it have not only arguments passed, but also environment variables and working directory. In python you can see them/print them using os.environ object, and os.getcwd() function. They are set by spawning process, so they may differ between those from cmd and from java. And they are important, because they could point to library paths and system path variables - which allows resolving python binaries (i.e. running wrong python version).